# Open3D: Creating a partial sphere

Tags: python, open3d

I am using Open3D with Python and would like to create a partial sphere based on limits for $\phi$ and $\theta$ (spherical coordinate representation). The `create_sphere` only allows me to create complete spheres.

```
import open3d as o3d
a = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_sphere()
a.compute_vertex_normals()
o3d.visualization.draw_plotly([a])
```

[image]

If Open3D is not the appropriate tool for this, I am open to using a different package and would like to create the partial sphere using that package.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: See [ask]. Research more, choose a proper framework and ask a specific question with a [mre]. You already know that ```Open3D``` does not provide that feature and you should implement it by yourself. Calculate vertices and triangle indices, and use the ```TriangleMesh``` constructor.

Comment: Thanks @relent95. I didn't know that Open3D doesn't provide that feature, thanks for pointing that out. I was hoping someone might know a built-in function. Also, I would appreciate any details or suggestions on what you mean by "calculating vertices and triangle indices" and then using them in the TriangleMesh constructor. Beginner with Open3D here.

Comment: It's not specific to Open3D. See [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_sphere.html) and [this](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/v0.17.0/cpp/open3d/geometry/TriangleMeshFactory.cpp#L216). Also see [this](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.utility.Vector3iVector.html#open3d.utility.Vector3iVector).

Comment: @relent95 Those links are really helpful, thank you. If I'm understanding you correctly, you would recommend creating the shape vertices/indices using numpy then importing to open3d?

Comment: Yes it is. Try them and edit the question if you confront a problem.